# What's the most efficient way to add spacing with a specific width to Widgets in a Row()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-row

I use Expanded() to tell the Widgets in my Row to use the available space. I want to have 4px space between elements in my Row. I don't want to have the same space towards elements outside of the Row. Given that Flutter doesn't support negative Padding I therefore can't add Padding in a way that gives the first item no left Padding and the last item no right Padding.

Is there pattern to easily define spacing with a specific width? I want a solution that works with an arbitrary number of Widgets. For 4 Widgets I want something that produces the equivalent of:

```
Row(children: [
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 0),
        child: Expanded(Text("Alice"))),
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
        child: Expanded(Text("Alice"))),
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
        child: Expanded(Text("Alice"))),
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
        child: Expanded(Text("Alice")))
]);
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of what you are conveying..that makes it a bit clear and easy to understand..

Comment: @srikanth7785 I added code for 4 Widgets with padding.

Comment: Did you try using `SizedBox`? You can use the `width` property to give space between the elements.

Comment: @Christian:  In your case, Expanded widgets will divide widgets with equal spaces. but I think that should work for you, that row first element will start from left side and remaining widgets will fill the remaining space. but if Expanded not found enough space to render in right side, it will shrink from there

Answer (score 0):

cant understand what you want to achieve exactly but try
Use `SizedBox` widget very easy and simple check it here

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html

example

```
  SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 300.0,
)
```

Comment: That leaves open the question of how to best put the SixedBoxes in between the Widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
    Widget(),
    Spacer(),
    Widget(),
    Widget(),
    ],
  ),
```

> Spacer, a widget that takes up space proportional to it's flex
>   value. [Flutter Row Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)
>
> mainAxisAlignment property : How the children should be placed along
>   the main axis. [Flutter MainAxisAlignment enum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html)

If you want to determine the size, you can use `SizedBox(width: double)` instead of `Spacer ()`.

> SizedBox: A box with a specified size. [Flutter SizedBox class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)